# Code-generated SWF to FLV

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flv, flash-cs5

I need to convert a swf movie that is created entirely through code (with the help of TweenLite) to a .flv format. The issue here is that I need to 1) Do this as a batch process, and that 2) since the swf is entirely generated by code it only has 1 frame and as such normal conversions like from CS5.5 to to the .avi format give me just 1 frame in the resulting video format. Is there a free converter out there that can get past the fact that my video is technically only 1 frame long and can handle batch jobs? Thanks for all your help

Comment: Step by step guide about [how to convert SWF to FLV](http://www.irbsoft.com/flash-tutorials/convert-swf-to-flv.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could implement a JSFL extension if you have a copy of Adobe Flash or a trial from their site.  It basically adds a command to publish multiple folders and sub folders.

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1021887

Comment: So as it turns out, JSFL is a plausible solution to this, though not quite in this way. What I didn't know is that JSFL files can be run from command line. The way this works for me is that I can create a default JSFL file and then dynamically modify it as I need through an external program. This external program would open the JSFL file, change it, and then run the JSFL file through command line, and voila! An automated .swf creation process that has more than 1 frame, thus allowing it to be converted by simpler video converters! :)